# how to get some part of a html body in php

Tags: php, html, curl

I want to get only some lines of an HTML body and I am using PHP with c URL (e.g. first 10 lines). By getting some part I mean that I don't want to download the whole file and get some parts of it.

Is there any way to get only some parts of HTML files from the server itself? by doing some setting in curl or PHP.

Answer (score 2):

If the server supports it, you can make a range request.

Add, to your HTTP request headers:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Range: 0-1500',
    ));
```

… to get the first 1500 bytes, which may or may not be the first ten lines, depending on how long the lines are.

The problem with this (aside from possible lack of support by the server) is that you need to know which bytes in the document you want and then you have to extract the data from a partial HTML instead of a complete HTML document.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CURL to download partial content from a URL:

Here's a function for that:

```
function curl_get_content($url,$range_start,$range_end)
{
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array ("Range: bytes=$range_start-$range_end"));
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
return $data;
}


curl_get_content("http://www.example.org/some-file.zip",0,5000)
```

returns the first 5000 bytes.

Notes:

**Finding out if HTTP 206 is supported or not by the remote server**

```
curl -I http://s0.cyberciti.org/images/misc/static/2012/11/ifdata-welcome-0.png
```

**Sample outputs:**

```
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Content-Type: image/png
Content-Length: 36907
Connection: keep-alive
Server: nginx
Date: Wed, 07 Nov 2012 00:44:47 GMT
X-Whom: l3-com-cyber
Cache-Control: public, max-age=432000000
Expires: Fri, 17 Jul 2026 00:44:46 GMT
Accept-Ranges: bytes // It accepts !
ETag: "278099835"
Last-Modified: Mon, 05 Nov 2012 23:06:34 GMT
Age: 298127
```

Comment: is there any way to count and terminate connection after receiving x bytes. ?

Comment: just set the maximum bytes to the number you want, it will disconnect after receiving the max bytes you set: ex: `curl_get_content("http://www.example.org/some-file.zip",0,3000)`, in this case it stops at 3000 bytes.

Comment: problem is range is not supported by some server. the answer you gave it involves range !!!