# How to use "if statement" in curl

Tags: php, if-statement, curl

My question is, I'm using curl to get spesific url from a site, but the site is very hude and loads slow, the part where i'm going to fetch is on the top of the page so the part i need loads fast. How to stop load the curl if my if statement is happened?

I tried =

```
    $con = curl_init();    
curl_setopt($con, CURLOPT_URL, $url_get);    
curl_setopt($con, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);    
curl_setopt($con, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);    
curl_setopt($con, CURLOPT_POST, true);    
curl_setopt($con, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.0; en-US; rv:1.4) Gecko/20030624 Netscape/7.1 (ax)");    
curl_setopt($con, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie_path);    
curl_setopt($con, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie_path);    
curl_setopt($con, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);    
curl_setopt($con, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true); 
$veri = curl_exec($con);   
if(preg_match("/value='(.*?)[+++](.*?)href='"$url"' style/", $veri, $dl)){
curl_close($con);
```

so if I get the $url in the page, it has to stop curl. Is it possible? Or any other ways to do it.
The value I need is $dl[1];

Comment: AFAIK, there isn't a way to only return part of the file. Manipulation of the file can only be done via PHP after the file has loaded.

Comment: Isn't it possible to stop fetching data from the page after x seconds?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to get some part of a html body in php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21133597/how-to-get-some-part-of-a-html-body-in-php)

Comment: Checked it, but i still doesn't solves the problem, remote server doesnt allow me to do the way that you shared. Thank you both btw.